# Access relationship table in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

We have a relationship table built with the below relationship between models.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html 
Though we can access the related model via the model instance. I am wondering how we can access the relationship table directly as I want to filter the records from the relationship table's custom field that we have added later in that relationship table.

For an example, after creating a new column (createdat) on AssemblyPart table, I would like to filter the record based on createdat columns.

At the moment, we are using execute method of connector to execute raw sql to access this relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

Use app to access all models individually if they aren't related to User Model:
Reference:

```
var app = require('../../server/server'); 
var ModelName = app.models.ModelName;
ModelName.find().then(data=>
{
 // Your Data
}).catch(error=>
{
 // error
})
```

Comment: That table has been created inclusively by loopback framework based on relationships defined in models. And since that model is not defined in model json file we can't access the model via app.